# In R, how can I look up a value in one column based on an interval in adjoining columns that includes values I want to match?

Tags: r, range, lookup, intervals, matching

In R, I have a reference table (dataframe) with three columns. Below is an example:

```
reftable <- data.frame(
  X_lower = c(0, 101, 181, 231, 280, 300, 340, 390, 500), 
  X_upper = c(100, 180, 230, 279, 299, 339, 389, 499, 600), 
  Percentile = c(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 15, 20, 25))

# X_lower     X_upper     Percentile
# 0           100         2
# 101         180         3
# 181         230         4
# etc.
```

I have a separate dataframe, `scores`, with specific values for X, and I want to use the reference table to look up the percentile rank associated with each value.

```
scores <- data.frame(
  X = c(58, 127, 175, 245, 300, 90, 405, 284, 330), 
  PercRank = NA))

# X        PercRank
# 58       ?
# 127      ?
# 175      ?
# 245      ?
# etc.
```

I've tried using match or findInterval but can't find a solution. I've searched through existing questions. If this has been asked before, I'm must not be hitting on the right search terms.

Comment: Try `foverlaps(setDT(scores1), setDT(reftable), type = "within")$Percentile#
[1]  2  8  2  3  3 11  6 20 11`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
scores$PercRank=sapply(scores$X,function(x){
  i = which(reftable$X_upper>x)[1]
  reftable$Percentile[i]
})

> scores
    X PercRank
1  58        2
2 127        3
3 175        3
4 245        6
5 300       11
6  90        2
7 405       20
8 284        8
9 330       11
```

Because `reftable` is ordered, you only need to check the first upper value bigger than your `X`.

Answer (score 2):

**1) sqldf** An SQL left join can be used:

```
library(sqldf)

scores$PercRank <- NULL

sqldf("select s.X, r.Percentile as PercRank
  from scores as s
  left join reftable as r on s.X between r.X_lower and r.X_upper")
```

giving:

```
    X PercRank
1  58        2
2 127        3
3 175        3
4 245        6
5 300       11
6  90        2
7 405       20
8 284        8
9 330       11
```

**2) findInterval** A base alternative is `findInterval`:

```
transform(scores, percRank = with(reftable, Percentile[ findInterval(X, X_lower) ]))
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** An option would be **`foverlaps`** from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
scores$PercRank <- foverlaps(scores1, reftable)[order(rn)]$Percentile
scores$rn <- NULL
scores
#     X PercRank
#1  58        2
#2 127        3
#3 175        3
#4 245        6
#5 300       11
#6  90        2
#7 405       20
#8 284        8
#9 330       11
```

**2)** Or use a **non-equi join**

```
setDT(scores)[reftable, PercRank := Percentile, on = .(X >= X_lower, X <= X_upper)]
scores
#     X PercRank
#1:  58        2
#2: 127        3
#3: 175        3
#4: 245        6
#5: 300       11
#6:  90        2
#7: 405       20
#8: 284        8
#9: 330       11
```

**3)** Or with **`fuzzyjoin`**

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_left_join(scores, reftable, by = c("X" = "X_lower", "X" = "X_upper"),
        match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)) %>% 
      select(X, Percentile)
#     X Percentile
#1  58          2
#2 127          3
#3 175          3
#4 245          6
#5 300         11
#6  90          2
#7 405         20
#8 284          8
#9 330         11
```

#### data

```
scores <- data.frame(
     X = c(58, 127, 175, 245, 300, 90, 405, 284, 330))
scores$rn <- seq_len(nrow(scores))
scores1 <- data.table(X_lower = scores$X, X_upper = scores$X, rn = scores$rn)
setkeyv(scores1, c("X_lower", "X_upper"))
setkeyv(reftable, c("X_lower", "X_upper"))
```